# Please identify this rose

Tags: identification

Please identify this rose for me.

[[image]][

Comment: Is it in flower now? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Maybe it's not a rose.

Comment: @Alina good point, now I've looked at the leaves, it doesn't seem to be a rose at all....

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Rambling Rose [(Rosa banksiae lutea)](https://www.classicroses.co.uk/rosa-banksiae-lutea-rambling-rose.html), but because only part of it is visible, its hard to be 100% sure - growth habit, height and spread are important factors for ID too. Common names include Lady Banks rose or just Banks rose. Note that pruning should be carried out immediately flowering is finished, unusually for a rambling rose; the others get pruned in September (in the northern hemisphere).

Comment: I went to the website you posted and I think you are right about the name of this rose. I looked at some of the lady bank roses at some local nurseries and the colors of those roses were either white or a yellow. Thank you for your reply. I hope to find one where I live in the southern part of the USA